# Why does this give the string index error

Tags: python

When i code this really simple example i get an error as followed: 'String index out of range', but i don't know why? What I'm trying is to simply print the first element of the first row of the matrix, so 'X' basically. I know there are easier ways of doing this, however the goal of the entire excercise is different and I'm trying to understand what it all means.

```
board = [
['X','X','X','X'],
['','','O','O'],
['X','O','X','X'],
['O','X','O','X']]
for row in board:
   print(row[0][0])
```

Comment: `for cell in row: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop do it like this

```
print(board[0][0])
```

Or if want to do it using for loop

```
for row in board:
    print(row[0])
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

because on the second row you have an empty string, it seems.

Comment: that's part of the exercise so that can't be the problem. Thanks for your answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
board = [
['X','X','X','X'],
['','','O','O'],
['X','O','X','X'],
['O','X','O','X']]
```

```
for row in board:
   print(row[0][0])
```

`board` is a 2D list (list of list). But one `row` in the board is a simple list.

You can access the first element directly:

```
board[0][0]
```

Or you have to do:

```
for row in board:
   print(row[0])
```

So, actually you want to select the column 0.
Why not:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(board)[0] # first column of board table
```

#### transpose

```
def transpose(lol): 
    return list(zip(*lol))

# so first column of `board`:
transpose(board)[0]
## ('X', '', 'X', 'O')
```

#### zipl (zip which returns lists and not tuples):

```
def zipl(*lists):
    return [[ l[i] for l in lists] for i in range(len(lists))]
    
def transpose(lol): # `lol`: list-of-lists
    return zipl(*lol)

transpose(board)
## [['X', '', 'X', 'O'],
##  ['X', '', 'O', 'X'],
##  ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O'],
##  ['X', 'O', 'X', 'X']]
```

Comment: Hello. So yeah I thought of the `board[0][0]` as well but my goal was to do it in a loop. Of course you showed that as well, however if I do that it would print every first element of every row. As for the last option you showed, we have seen something about modules but we haven't really used them yet so for me that one would be to complicated eventhough it might be simple. Thanks for your answer and help!

Comment: welcome! You could write a function `def transpose(lol): return list(zip(*lol))` - and then try: `transpose(board)`. This `flips` the matrix by its diagnoal (left up to down right diagonal). So: `transpose(board)[0]` is the first column of `board` and `transpose(board)[1]` is the second column etc.

Answer (score -1):

Because for the second row (`['', '', 'O', 'O']`) `row[0]` will be `''` and hence `row[0][0]`, i.e. `''[0]`, won't exist (an empty string doesn't have a first character, it has none whatsoever!). Currently you are looping over rows, so the first indexing operation on the row will access a *cell* (which yields a string) and the second one will then access *the characters in the string*.

According to what you said you'd like to achieve, you want to just have `board[0][0]` without any `for` at all:

```py
board = [
  ['X','X','X','X'],
  ['','','O','O'],
  ['X','O','X','X'],
  ['O','X','O','X']
]

print(board[0][0])
```